# How to use type: importedCompenent in Vue3 compenent props?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Let's say I have 2 compenents:

todoItem:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'todoItem',
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isCompleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
  },
});
```

And I want to do the following
todoList:

```
import TodoItem from './TodoItem.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'todoList',
  props: {
    todos: {
      type: Array<TodoItem>, // Gives an error
      required: false,
    },
  },
  components: {
    TodoItem,
  },
});
```

Is there a way I can do the following?
I can "duplicate" it as a typescript interface by doing:

```
interface Todo: {name: String, isCompleted: Boolean}

// then do
type: Array as PropType<Todo[]>
```

But it's duplicate code and i'll need to refactor it every time there's a change.

Is there a better way?

Comment: From the code it's unclear what exactly `todos` will. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I *think* you can define types in a file `src/typings/todo.d.ts` for example (it supposedly automatically reads from `src/typings`, but I have not come to the point yet where I have tried this out.

Comment: @EstusFlask todos will be destructured into todoItems.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with an interface. This is a business logic concern, so you should have some sort of business logic data model. It is then converted to TodoItem components at the end. The UI and the business logic are separate things so they don't need to share code at this level.

Comment: This doesn't explain much. Does `todos` contain component itself? Or refs to component instances? Please, provide the example of how this prop is used. It's unclear how it should be typed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From your provided code I guess you don't need to use props inside the `TodoList` component, given `TodoList` and `TodoItem` are a pair of parent-child component. You can try below code to pass data between them:

`TodoItem.vue`: nothing need to change.

`TodoList.vue`:

```
<template>
  <TodoItem :name="todos.name" :isCompleted="todos.isCompleted" />
</template>

import { ref } from 'vue
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'todoList',
  components: {
    TodoItem
  },
  setup() {
    const todos = ref({
      name: '',
      isCompleted: false
    })
    return {
      todos
    }
  }
});
```

or you can pass `name` and `isCompleted` separately, meaning getting rid of `todos`:

`TodoList.vue`:

```
<template>
  <TodoItem :name="name" :isCompleted="isCompleted" />
</template>

import { ref } from 'vue
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'todoList',
  components: {
    TodoItem
  },
  setup() {
    const name = ref('')
    const isCompleted = ref(false)
    })
    return {
      name,
      isCompleted
    }
  }
});
```

Above are for one-way data pass (from TodoList to TodoItem). If you are seeking two-way data pass, you can try `setup(props, {emit})` in TodoItem.vue.